# Google script- sending automatic email based with conditions

Tags: google-apps-script

Hope you'll be able to help me, I'm a very beginner for google script (and coding in general)!

My main objective is to send automatically an email everytime that a task is not completed for more than 7 days.

here is my [sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/18jniLLkgowXbOyzR-HcxAUtlBqFbNo5PVSjZELEte68/edit?usp=sharing/%22google%20sheets%22)

In details, my file is to report problem on customer's orders. So you'll find many columns but the only used for this case are : the date that the problem the problem(C), the order number (D) and the reason of the problem(I,J,K,L).

In my script I want to send an email to this email address (xxx@xxx.xx), every time that a problem is not solved for more than 7 days.
The idea is to receive a mail saying "Be careful, the problem of the order n° //variable// hasn't been solved for more than //variable//. This problem because of //variable//"

When I ran the code, it gets me no error message but I didn't receive any mail either..

Here is my code :

```
 function sendEmails() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  ss.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheetByName("Envoi mail"));
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange("A2:H40");
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  for (i in data) {
    var rowData = data[i];
    var commande = rowData[1];
    var jourretard = rowData[2];
    var raison1 = rowData[3];
    var raison2 = rowData[4];
    var raison3 = rowData[5];
    var raison4 = rowData[6];
    var execute = rowData[7]; 
    var message = 'Attention, un incident sur la commande n°' + commande + '.' + 'En attente de résolution depuis' + jourretard + '. Il est dû à' + raison1 + raison2+ raison3+ raison4+'.';
    var subject = 'Incident non-traité'; 
if (execute == "yes"){
MailApp.sendEmail('xxx@xxx.xx', subject, message);
  }
}}
```

Thanks a lot and have a good day,
Alex

Comment: Confirm please that you don't care about the first column of data, `rowData[0]`. Arrays are 0-base and also should not be iterated with the *property enumeration* method **for...in**` (conduct an internet search to learn why). When you set a breakpoint and execute this script in debug mode, do you notice about the variables you have defined?

Comment: There is no rowdata[7]. Your choice is 0-6.

Comment: Sorry my mistake, I corrected to write from 0 to 6 (instead of 1 to 7..)
Now that I changed the numbers, I can't even access the debug mode. When I try it, it starts launching, open the window and close it straight..

Considering not using **for...in**, I found many reasons why not using it but I didn't understand what should I do in my specific case

Comment: Instead of `for ... in`, you should use `for (var i = 0; i < dataRange.length; i++)`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answers,
I answered below and added the new code

Comment: Sorry to bother you, may you have a solution for my case ?
I received many times a mail from google, resuming the failure and it says that I have too many triggers.

Comment: It appears that triggers are setting up themself and I finally have a huge list of triggers..

Thanks a lot again,

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code that I've updated; I modified :
 - the "rowData[0]" numbers
 - I changed "for (var i = 0; i < dataRange.length; i++)"
 - I added a trigger to execute it everyday

But it still doesn't do anything (no mail received and impossible to use the debug mode ..)

```js
ScriptApp.newTrigger("sendEmails")
  .timeBased()
  .everyDays(1)
  .create();

function sendEmails() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  ss.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheetByName("Envoi email"));
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange("A2:G25");
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  for (var i = 0; i < dataRange.length; i++) {
    var rowData = data[i];
    var commande = rowData[0];
    var jourretard = rowData[1];
    var raison1 = rowData[2];
    var raison2 = rowData[3];
    var raison3 = rowData[4];
    var raison4 = rowData[5];
    var execute = rowData[6]; 
    var message = 'Attention, un incident sur la commande n°' + commande + '.' + 'En attente de résolution depuis' + jourretard + '. Il est dû à' + raison1 + raison2+ raison3+ raison4+'.';
    var subject = 'Incident non-traité'; 
if (execute == "yes"){
MailApp.sendEmail('contact@xxx.x', subject, message);
  }
}}


here are my OAuth ot the project:
"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.scriptapp
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.send_mail
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets"
```

If you have an idea, don't hesitate :)

I also have a question, (that may looks stupid sorry but I checked and didn't find ..) regarding the execution of the script, does "getActiveSpreadsheet" means that the script can't be executed with the file closed ?

And many thanks for your time and help !